# What is the correct way to "hook" into app.response functions in express?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I need to way to add some data to app.json and app.jsonp responses in express after app.json is called, what is the correct way to add middleware to this?  I know I could probably do something like:

```
var jsonTemp = function(status, data) {
  if (!data) {
    data = status;
    status = 200;
  }
  data.extraValue = 'foo';
  res.json(status, data);

}
res.json = jsonTemp;
```

but monkey patching like that seems like a "bad idea".  Is there an official way to hook into the response with some kind of middleware?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "hook into the response"?  The response is an object.  The request is the event.  Do you mean "hook into the request" somehow?

Comment: You can write middleware for urls and insert your logic there

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear, I need to be able to add data to a JSON result after the rest.json was called so it can't be done in the usual middleware location since it happens after the standard handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that monkey patching actually might be the best solution without knowing more about what problem you are trying to solve. The code you showed does however crash the server so don't use that.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  var orig = res.json;
  res.json = function json(status, data) {

    if (!data) {
      data = status;
      status = 200;
    }

    data.extraValue = 'foo';
    orig.call(this, status, data);
  };

  next();
});
```

Here I'm storing the original function in the variable `orig` and then delegating to that one when I'm done with the modification. Your code called your modified function over and over again, since that one now lives under `res.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your own [template engine](http://expressjs.com/advanced/developing-template-engines.html) to format your output. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Creating a json view renderer seems like a bad hack to just get access to json before it is sent back to the user.

Comment: I do agree. By the way, why do you need changing the JSON output after is produced? Can you give a example of use, please? Maybe we can think on a better way to solve this.

Comment: Currently I need to pass the session cookie as JSON value if cookies are not being supported.   Yes I could add a function call to every time I produce JSON, but there are 50+ uses over 5 files and missing or forgetting to add it will just lead to errors only in places that don't support cookies which will be difficult to debug).  I can imagine other uses like adding tamper protection from man-in-middle attacks by adding a SHA-1 checksum to all the fields.