# Express middleware to wrap response

Tags: node.js, express

I'm implementing an API where the result needs to be return wrapped by a result key, as such

```
{
  result: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Bob"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is add a piece of middleware (if possible) that does this wrapping to every response without having to think about it every time. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I could see modifying `response.body` and then calling `next()` instead of doing `res.send(obj)` (what I'm doing now).

Thanks!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256179/what-is-the-correct-way-to-hook-into-app-response-functions-in-express/28431834#28431834

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up extending the response object to add a new function (used like `res.sendWrapped(data)`) per [In Express and Node.js, is it possible to extend or override methods of the response object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304436/in-express-and-node-js-is-it-possible-to-extend-or-override-methods-of-the-resp)
as such:

```
express.response.sendWrapped = function(obj) {
    return this.send({ result: obj });
};
```